# Tables: How to achieve "normal" td widths, but 100% table width?

Tags: html

On our site we have tables containing data. We like the column widths we get with a normal `table`, but we like the border-bottom of `td`s to stretch the entire width of the page like we get with CSS: `table { width:100% }`, as can be seen on a [demo table widths page](http://www.morch.com/download/tableWidth/tableWidths.html).

Is it possible to achieve the same column widths as with a normal (non-width-100%) table in a table where the border-bottom stretches the entire width?

Btw, is there *a better way* (tm) of showing HTML snippets than linking to an external page? I can show just source, but having HTML rendered too is *so* illustrative.

We need a solution that works in at least IE6-8 + FF.

Answer (score 1):

Adding **#tableB td { float: left; }** will give you the desired effect in current browsers (IE8+, Chrome, Firefox etc). However this does not work in IE7.

You can see an approach offered for dealing with floating td's in conjunction with IE7: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018125/ie7-how-to-make-td-float.

Note that the above suggested workaround uses invalid markup to achieve what I believe you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I need to support IE6-8 and FF. So also IE7. And the IE7 workaround fixes the column widths, and then we're nowhere... But thanks for the suggestion. I'll edit the description to mention the cross-browser requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `td { white-space: nowrap }` the lines 'Foo Bar' and 'Hello World' will stay intact. Is this what you're after?

Comment: That doesn't work if the contents of a TD are very long. A "normal" table starts wrapping at some point, whereas `td { white-space: nowrap }` will never wrap. So no that won't work for us as some `td` s are very long.

What I'm after is the same behaviour as "normal" tables/cells. That wrap under the same conditions.

Comment: Hmm, tough one. I wonder at what exact point a "normal" table starts wrapping, it must be in the specifications somewhere. Maybe you should ask this over at StackOverflow.com

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering that. Stackoverflow is for "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers" and Webmasters is for "Q&A for pro webmasters". I assumed HTML/CSS questions were for Webmasters. But I'll post on Stackoverflow instead. Thanks, Litso!

Comment: [new question at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434527/tables-how-to-achieve-normal-td-widths-but-100-table-width)